# Spring Junit org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Exception opening port "9092" (port may be in use)

Tags: java, spring, junit, h2

My application build with Spring Boot, Hibernate, JUnit. I use H2 database for in memory testing and created a bean to be able to connect to H2 database with SQL tool.

```
@Configuration
public class H2DataBaseTestConfig {
    @Bean(initMethod = "start", destroyMethod = "stop")
    public Server h2Server() throws SQLException {
        return Server.createTcpServer("-tcp", "-tcpAllowOthers", "-tcpPort", "9092");
    }
}
```

It works fine if I run one test, but if I run all tests I get an error on second and all next test classes

```
Exception opening port "9092" (port may be in use)
```

This looks like Spring tries to create application context and initiates bean every time next test class will run, though this conflicts somehow with port opened by itself. **How can I run all tests and have this bean working?**

**Update**

As many people mention test classes annotations, I will show them here:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(IndeedScraper.class)
@TestPropertySource(locations="classpath:test.properties")
```

I have few @Configuration classes: two database connection/transaction/entity management classes and described here h2Server bean. h2Server bean builder class is stored in src/test/java, while other @Configuration classes in src/main/java

**End Update**

Here full stack trace for reference:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:124)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:83)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:117)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:83)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:228)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:230)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:291)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:249)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:89)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:193)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:678)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'h2Server' defined in class path resource [healthjobs/scraper/H2DataBaseTestConfig.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Exception opening port "9092" (port may be in use), cause: "java.net.BindException: Address already in use (Bind failed)" [90061-192]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1578)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:772)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:839)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:538)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:760)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createAndRefreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:306)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.SpringApplicationContextLoader.loadContext(SpringApplicationContextLoader.java:98)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:98)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:116)
    ... 25 more
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Exception opening port "9092" (port may be in use), cause: "java.net.BindException: Address already in use (Bind failed)" [90061-192]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:345)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:168)
    at org.h2.util.NetUtils.createServerSocketTry(NetUtils.java:199)
    at org.h2.util.NetUtils.createServerSocket(NetUtils.java:165)
    at org.h2.server.TcpServer.start(TcpServer.java:232)
    at org.h2.tools.Server.start(Server.java:484)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeCustomInitMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1706)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1645)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1574)
    ... 40 more
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use (Bind failed)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketBind(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.bind(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:387)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.bind(ServerSocket.java:375)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:237)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:128)
    at org.h2.util.NetUtils.createServerSocketTry(NetUtils.java:195)
    ... 50 more
```

Comment: you can use @Autowire instead of creating bean for every test case.

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you are doing this `Server.createTcpServer` ? Springboot automatically connects to h2 database

Comment: @Nidhi257 Could you explain what you mean? How Autowire prevent bean creation?

Comment: Try to connect using a method with "@Before" annotation within that Test class and eventually closing TCP connection on one "@After" annotated method

Comment: @pvpkiran Yes Spring Boot application will connect to database, but I did this bean to have second connection with other SQL client to see content of tables while testing.

Comment: @nineunderground could you show some sample?

Comment: you have created bean in H2DataBaseTestConfig class. you can autowire this and open and close the connection onces in methods with "@Before" and  "@After" annotation and can use the same bean to  get data from DB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the options can be sharing a Spring context between your test classes as described in this [integration test tutorial](https://spring.io/blog/2011/06/21/spring-3-1-m2-testing-with-configuration-classes-and-profiles) and also pay attention to context caching description in [Spring documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/integration-testing.html#testcontext-ctx-management-caching)

That is, to share same runtime context to your unit test classes, try to annotate all of your unit tests which need H2 connection as follows:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
...
@ContextConfiguration(classes=H2DataBaseTestConfig.class, loader=AnnotationConfigContextLoader.class)
public class SomeServiceTest {
    ...
```

Note, that this approach does not rely on SpringBoot integration testing support which is referred in another answer in this thread.

**Update**

As it seems not obvious, you may need to list all another necessary @Configuration-annotated classes in there like `@ContextConfiguration(classes={H2Config.class, MyConfigFromSrcTest.class, MyConfigFromSrcMain.class, ...}, ...` to reflect superset of all context pieces which are required by your integration test classes. And resulting context then will be cached by using exact set of those configuration classes as cache key

Comment: Is this mean that H2DataBaseTestConfig class bean will be loaded before every test class started? If such, I already have this, bean instantiated on every test class run. Or this will share H2DataBaseTestConfig between all test classes? Should I delete Configuration annotation before near H2DataBaseTestConfig class name?

Comment: Leave your `@Configuration` annotation in place. Just add `@ContextConfiguration` as described, which will force Spring to cache and re-use context configured with the same `H2DataBaseTestConfig` instead of creating context each time new unit test class is being executed

Comment: When I added <code>@ContextConfiguration</code> my other Autowired beans in test class not work any more - org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException. See my question update.

Comment: Added Update section with regards to your comment

Comment: Sorry for long silence. Your idea was interesting from start point, but I was not able to check everything fast. The problem was I messed up context description between tests. I found the context cache description here: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/integration-testing.html#testcontext-ctx-management-caching

Answer (score 1):

```
@Before
public void setUp() {
    createTCPConnection();
}

@After
public void endTest() {
    closeTCPConnection();
}

@Test
public void firstTest() {
    doTest(1);
}

@Test
public void secondTest() {
    doTest(2);
}
```

Then all your running tests are called between before and after. So, the connection it's created once for that class and all Test methods on it

Comment: I not checked this, as found problem solution with test context cache. Though it looks like your idea could work either. Thanks.